# Passing to Java int[] from Jython PyList

Tags: reflection, jython

Now I am stucked with the specific question, asking for you guys' help.

**KeyWords:**
Java Reflection, Jython PyList, NoSuchMethodException

**Java Side:**

targetMethod(**int []**)   is the method exactly I want to call by reflecting. Do pay attention to the int [] param.

**Jython Side:**

l_params = [1,2,3]

**Problem:**

When I tried to do the reflection call by passing **type(l_params)**,  got info below:

*java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: **targetMethod(org.python.core.PyList)**
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Unknown Source)*

So how to deal with it?  Hoping to get a light from you.

Answer (score 0):

Yeap, one possible solution —— Proxy：

**Jython** ----**Java Proxy** ---- **Target Method**

Though the Target Method is un-controllable, we can do whatever we want to within the Java Proxy.

But how to want to solve this without the proxy ?

//added at 2015/11/23

Thanks to the flexibility of jython, now i just fix this by mixing jython and java

**jython side:**

import javaArray

java.getType(paramType)

**java side:** //javaArray.java

public static Class getType(String strType)

{

```
if (strType.equals("[I"))
        return (new int[0]).getClass();
```

}

Really need to dig more about jython, java, if you want to hack on it.

Thanks.

//

//added at 2015/11/26

Really a shame to write code like that without using Class.forName.........

public static Class getType(String strType)

{

```
//try...catch 
ret = Class.forName(strType);
return ret;
```

}